# PHP composer, uso de require etiqueta + hash

Tags: php, git, github

Estoy intentando instalar los vendor de una aplicación y tengo un error un poco extraño:

> Installation request for sg/datatablesbundle
>   dev-master#73ac0ed0ba5adbfe0139b19e1f1c073f4e4c120a -> satisfiable by
>   sg/datatablesbundle[dev-master].
>
> sg/datatablesbundle dev-master
>   requires friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle 1.6.0 -> no matching
>   package found.

Revisando el paquete `datatablesbundle`, veo que `dev-master` requiere el `jsrouting-bundle` version 1.6.0 y dice que este paquete no existe, pero en github y en packagist aparecen.

Tengo como requisito que `datatablebundle` sea de ese commit en concreto. Si reviso [dicho commit en github](https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/commit/73ac0ed0ba5adbfe0139b19e1f1c073f4e4c120a) veo que es ahora de la rama v0.13, por lo que creo que en  `composer` debo escribir en la sección `require` algo tipo:

```
"friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.6.0",
"sg/datatablesbundle": "**v0.13#73ac0ed0ba5adbfe0139b19e1f1c073f4e4c120a**",
```

Cosa que no funciona.

Actualmente tengo:

```
"friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "dev-master",
"sg/datatablesbundle": "dev-master#73ac0ed0ba5adbfe0139b19e1f1c073f4e4c120a",
```

Pero no consigo solucionarlo. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea sobre cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Una solución es indicar que cargue la versión `dev-master` como si fuera la versión `1.6.0` haciendo uso de un [`alias inline`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias):

```
{
  "name": "redstar/temporal",
  "description": "Descripción",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Óscar García",
      "email": "...@..."
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "dev-master as 1.6.0",
    "sg/datatablesbundle": "dev-master#73ac0ed0ba5adbfe0139b19e1f1c073f4e4c120a"
  }
}
```

Comment: no conocia el uso del alias inline del composer. Con esto se soluciona el problema que he planteado, aunque ahora me da otro por conflictos con otro bundle (pero eso ya para otro stackoverflow :) ) gracias!!!

Comment: De nada, un placer. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como solución correcta. Luego echo un vistazo al siguiente problema que sufres.

Comment: sin problema, ya esta marcada la solucion. lo unico que todavia no tengo una "reputacion" para que se vea :(

Comment: Ahí van 5 puntos :)

Comment: Gran dato! Yo me daba un rodeo absurdo envolviendo paquetes en otros y usando `provides`